# How to fetch all hits in lucene.net

Tags: .net, lucene.net, wildcard, fetch, hints

I want to fetch all hits from lucene. Is there any wild card character which fetches all records?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and describe how it hasn't worked, alternatively perhaps the Lucene documentation might be a good place to start?

Comment: Do you mean you want to return all documents from Lucene rather than all Hits?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might this class in Lucene.Net serve your purpose? MatchAllDocsQuery

Answer (score 14):

It worked. Thank You.

The code goes like this:

```
searcher = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher(IndexPath);    
Lucene.Net.Search.MatchAllDocsQuery objMatchAll = new Lucene.Net.Search.MatchAllDocsQuery();    
Lucene.Net.Search.Hits hits = searcher.Search(objMatchAll);
```